# issue with for loops in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and I am trying to implement a for loop where I want to loop through and store all the text values of all a tags.

But I am only able to get the text of one single a tag.

This is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary


*** Variables ***
${url}  http://www.practiceselenium.com/practice-form.html


*** Test Cases ***
ExtractLinks
    alllinks

    close browser


*** Keywords ***
allLinks
    open browser    ${url}

    ${allLinksCount}    get element count    xpath://a
    log to console  ${allLinksCount}


    FOR     ${i}     IN      1  ${allLinksCount}

    ${linkText}     get text    xpath:(//a)[${i}]

    log to console    ${linkText}

    END
```

This is the output:

```
==============================================================================
getAllLinks
==============================================================================
ExtractLinks                                                          10
More

ExtractLinks                                                          | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
getAllLinks                                                           | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

So there are 10 a tags on the page, but only one is shown, "More" in the output to the console.

Is it all possible to gather all a link text in list instead?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVy2M5BSK3k

Comment: Use your for loop like this `FOR     ${i}     IN RANGE    ${allLinksCount+1}`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to write the whole IN RANGE keyword :) I did try to use the +1 in ${allLinksCount+1}, but then I get a error "Variable definition not found"
With just the ${allLinksCount} I get 8 results and not 10??

Answer (score 2):

`FOR     ${i}     IN      1  ${allLinksCount}` is equivalent to the python code `for i in (1, 10)`. In other words, it will loop exactly twice.

If you're wanting to iterate over the *range* of numbers between `1` and `${allLinksCount}` you should use `IN RANGE`.

Because xpath counts starting with one instead of zero, you'll need to adjust the numbers slightly:

```
FOR     ${i}     IN RANGE     1  ${allLinksCount}+1
    ${linkText}     get text    xpath:(//a)[${i}]
    log to console   ${linkText}
END
```

-or-

```
FOR     ${i}     IN RANGE     ${allLinksCount}
    ${linkText}     get text    xpath:(//a)[${i+1}]
    log to console   ${linkText}
END
```